# Using GSL Minimize in C++

Tags: c++, c

I am having a problem with Minimization library in GSL. I am trying to implement the  algorithm without derivatives, but in order to used i need to pass the function to minimize:

https://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/doc/html/multimin.html?highlight=minimization

I am following what they have there for the algorithm without derivatives, but when i try to used in my member class function: my_func i get this:

‘Class::my_func’ from type ‘double (Class::)(const gsl_vector*, void*)’ to type ‘double (*)(const gsl_vector*, void*)’

It seems the algorithm cannot use a member class function. My question is how to bypass this and transform the member class function into a normal (C like) function?

Answer (score 1):

GSL uses `params` to pass arbitrary parameters into your function. Use a pointer to your object as "parameters".

Make a proxy function, a `static` member function in your class, which receives `params`. Inside this function, convert `params` to the proper type (pointer to your `Class`), and call the member function in it.

If your `my_func` is `public`, you can use a non-member ("global") proxy function.

```
class Class
{
    double my_func(const gsl_vector*) // the real function
    {
        ...
    }

    static double static_my_func(const gsl_vector* v, void* params) // proxy function
    {
        Class* object = static_cast<Class*>(params);
        return object->my_func(v);
    }
};
```

If your real function wants to receive additional parameters, you have to accommodate this somehow, e.g. making the parameters members of your `Class`, or (more complicated but more object-oriented) creating a temporary `struct`, which contains a pointer to your object and the additional parameters.

Comment: Ok, now it works, but i forgot to mention that my function my_like is double, not a constant gsl_vector, is it any way to transform it?. My function uses a pointer and not the gsl_vector: compiler says:
no known conversion for argument 1 from ‘const gsl_vector*’ to ‘double*’